# Instalação Framework Foundation

Tags: foundation

Estou tentando instalar o Foundation mas não estou conseguindo, ja instalei o GIT e o NODEjs e ao digitar a linha de comando no prompt gera as instruções abaixo, alguém pode me dar um auxilio?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: e essa questao conseguiu resolver? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272953/cria%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-colunas-no-foundation

Comment: eu não sei se é isso, como não dava certo eu imaginei que fosse derepente algo na instalação, agora não sei de de fato esta instalado ou se estou digitando o código errado, toda a documentação do Foundation eu li mas não sei porque esta com esse erro minha maquina

Comment: cara, pro framework funcionar voce tem que colocar na sua pagina somente os links do arquivo js e css, como eu respondi lá.. e o hugo tb, copia as 3 primeiras linhas do exemplo (link, script, e o outro script) cola elas no seu arquivo e puff, o framework ja vai estar funcionando em sua pagina